# Отправка переменной res.send

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Работаю с Node.JS с Express.
Имеется var переменная, которую с помощью res.send я хочу передать на сайт (localhost)
И отобразить её в виде числа(текста). Каким куском кода я могу это сделать?

Comment: Проблема XY... Код, нам нужен код..

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/bS7Zfra там и парсер даты и создание страницы. Хз как совместить, чтобы на странице просто выводилась переменная( Точнее её значение.

Comment: Для начала можно здесь почитать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking